# Why this piece of java code with generics doesn't compile

Tags: java, generics, compiler-construction

Test.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Iterator;

class Wrapper<T> {
    public T content;
    public ArrayList<Wrapper> children;
}

public class Test {
    public static void testing (Stack<Wrapper> stack) {
        Wrapper test = stack.pop();

        Iterator<Wrapper> itr = test.children.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Wrapper item = itr.next();
            System.out.println(item.content);
        }

        ArrayList<Wrapper> canCompile = test.children;
        for (Wrapper child : canCompile) {
            System.out.println(child.content);
        }

        for (Wrapper child : test.children) {
            System.out.println(child.content);
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Test.java:25: error: incompatible types
        for (Wrapper child : test.children) {
                                 ^
  required: Wrapper
  found:    Object
Note: Test.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

My question isn't how to get this code to work. But rather why this code as it stands doesn't compile. The above code uses generics in a way that's unorthodox, and it also yields compilation warnings. However I would still expect the compiler to have enough information to compile the above piece of code.

Comment: Wrapper<T> where is the T in Stack<Wrapper>? I think it should be something like Stack<Wrapper<something>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However I would still expect the compiler to have enough information to compile the above piece of code.

No it doesn't. Because you didn't gave the compiler enough information.

You are using a raw type `Wrapper` in your code, in which case, all the generic type information is not available to the compiler. So, the compiler sees `ArrayList<Wrapper>` as just `ArrayList`, and that is why when you iterate over it, you'll get back `Object` type values and not `Wrapper` type.

See [JLS § 4.8 - Raw Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) for more details:

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or non-static field (§8.3) M of a raw type C that is not inherited from its superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to C.

**Also See:**

- [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/1679863)

Answer (score 1):

You declared

```
Wrapper test = stack.pop();
```

You are using `Wrapper` as a [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8). As such, at compile time, all methods and fields that have generic components appear as their erasure.

So

```
public ArrayList<Wrapper> children;
```

appears as

```
public ArrayList children;
```

The `iterator()` method of `ArrayList` is declared as

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
```

where `E` is `ArrayList`'s type parameter. Its erasure becomes

```
public Iterator iterator() {
```

The `Iterator#next()` method is declared as

```
E next();
```

so its erasure in turn becomes

```
Object next();
```

You're implicitly (through the for-each loop) trying to assign a value of type `Object` to a reference of type `Wrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't type your `Wrapper`,

```
public static void testing (Stack<Wrapper> stack) // <-- Here
```

or

```
 Wrapper test = stack.pop(); // <-- or here.
```

And, that is why that isn't generic. You should have `Wrapper<TYPE>` where `TYPE` is appropriate.